# Azure domain name mapping

Tags: azure, dns, mapping

Accidentlly I purchased a domain from azure app service. Now I want to map this into a azure cloud service. can abody help me.
   I tried in google but I didn't get any result for this

Answer (score 1):

-Go to Network Interface Card(NIC) which is associated with your VM.

-Click on All settings, then there is DNS servers field.

-Click on Dns server field,then there is a tab which shows you the Azure DNS and Custom DNS.

-If you have purchased DNS then select custom DNS and then type your Primary and Secondary DNS Server name.

-If you have only 1 DNS name then type it only Primary DNS Server name and then Save it.

-Now you can access it using your DNS.